# Use ES6 functions defined in a separate file with gulp and babel

Tags: javascript, gulp, ecmascript-6, babeljs, gulp-concat

I've been stuck on trying to split my code into several files then compile with babel and combine into one file for a while now.

I have two files, functions.js and main.js

functions.js looks like:

```
//distance between two points
const distance = (p1, p2) => Math.sqrt(Math.pow((p2.x - p1.x), 2) + Math.pow((p2.y - p1.y), 2));

//slope of line through p1, p2
const slope = (p1, p2) => (p2.x - p1.x) / (p2.y - p1.y);

//etc.
```

Then the code in main.js needs to use these functions. 
My gulpfile looks like:

```
'use strict';

var projectname = 'canvas-test',
  template_path = '',
  scss_path = template_path + 'scss/**/*.scss',
  es2015_path = template_path + 'es2015/**/*.js',
  scripts_path = template_path + 'scripts/',
  gulp = require('gulp'),
  watch = require('gulp-watch'),
  babel = require('gulp-babel'),
  livereload = require('gulp-livereload'),
  concat = require('gulp-concat');

//Put all javascript tasks here
gulp.task('js', function() {
  return gulp.src(es2015_path + '/**/*.js')
    .pipe(concat('main.js'))
    .pipe(babel({
      presets: ['es2015']
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(scripts_path))
    .pipe(livereload());
});

//default task
gulp.task('default', ['js'], function() {
  livereload.listen();
  gulp.watch(es2015_path, ['js']);
});
```

The file ./scripts/main.js is compiled, concated and created succesfully, however I can't use the functions as they are wrapped in a messy closure added by babel:

```
(function e(t,n,r){function s(o,u){if(!n[o]){if(!t[o]){var a=typeof require=="function"&&require;if(!u&&a)return a(o,!0);if(i)return i(o,!0);var f=new Error("Cannot find module '"+o+"'");throw f.code="MODULE_NOT_FOUND",f}var l=n[o]={exports:{}};t[o][0].call(l.exports,function(e){var n=t[o][1][e];return s(n?n:e)},l,l.exports,e,t,n,r)}return n[o].exports}var i=typeof require=="function"&&require;for(var o=0;o<r.length;o++)s(r[o]);return s})({1:[function(require,module,exports){

///COMPILED CODE FROM FUNCTIONS.JS HERE


},{}],2:[function(require,module,exports){
'use strict';

var _createClass = function () { function defineProperties(target, props) { for (var i = 0; i < props.length; i++) { var descriptor = props[i]; descriptor.enumerable = descriptor.enumerable || false; descriptor.configurable = true; if ("value" in descriptor) descriptor.writable = true; Object.defineProperty(target, descriptor.key, descriptor); } } return function (Constructor, protoProps, staticProps) { if (protoProps) defineProperties(Constructor.prototype, protoProps); if (staticProps) defineProperties(Constructor, staticProps); return Constructor; }; }();

function _classCallCheck(instance, Constructor) { if (!(instance instanceof Constructor)) { throw new TypeError("Cannot call a class as a function"); } }

//COMPILED CODE FROM MAIN.JS HERE


},{"./functions.js":1}]},{},[2]);
```

I've spent quite a while looking for a solution to this, tried using bBrowserify and a few other things but to no avail. Is there any simple way to do this?

Comment: Learn about modules: http://www.2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import,

Comment: Thanks, but I've already spent quite a while trying to get exports working to no avail. 
For a start, any documentation I've read is quite unclear as to whether exports will even work with gulp/babel, then I've tried lots of different variations from the pages you linked such as:

In functions.js: _export const distance = (p1,p2) -> {...}_

OR _const  distance = (p1,p2) -> {...};_
_export {distance}_

in main.js: _import distance from 'functions'_
OR _import * as name from './functions.js'_ and so on.

The result is always the same: _Uncaught ReferenceError: distance is not defined_

Comment: If you are using named exports (`export const foo = ...;`) then you also have to use named imports: `import {foo} from '...';`). If you are using modules, you have to use a module bundler, like browserify, you cannot simply concat the files. Gulp/babel don't care whether you use modules or not, they only look at one file at a time.

Comment: Well as I mentioned I already spent quite a while trying to get browserify to work with either export or require statement, but to no avail. And as you can see from my previous comment the named export thing is not working for me either. 
The approach I am taking this time is to attempt to concatenate the files BEFORE babel compiles them. Is this not possible?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if this is obvious, have you tried swapping the order in which babel transpiles?

I recall having some goofy behavior by calling *concat* before *babel*. I generally pipe babel in and then concat/uglify/rename etc.